# Mingw64 compiler adds __debugbreak and __fastfail to each source file error

Tags: windows, googletest, mingw-w64

I'm trying to build GoogleTest C++ code to test a static C library. The setup is to statically link the library under test to the test application. Everything builds and links fine on Linux. But on Windows, using MINGW64 shell, there are  multiple definition of `__debugbreak` and `__fastfail` errors. It looks like the compiler adds these two functions to *each* C source file object. Compiling the same CMake setup in the regular PowerShell works fine.

```
cd C:/Users/Ilya/work/build/foc_lib/test && C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/cmake.exe -E rm -f CMakeFiles/widget-a0_test.dir/objects.a
cd C:/Users/Ilya/work/build/foc_lib/test && C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/ar.exe qc CMakeFiles/widget-a0_test.dir/objects.a @CMakeFiles/widget-a0_test.dir/objects1
cd C:/Users/Ilya/work/build/foc_lib/test && C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe  -Wall -Wextra -Werror -fno-exceptions -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pedantic -O0 -DNDEBUG -g -Wl,--whole-archive CMakeFiles/widget-a0_test.dir/objects.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive -o widget-a0_test.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libwidget-a0_test.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 @CMakeFiles/widget-a0_test.dir/linkLibs.rsp
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: ../libwidget-a0.a(maths.c.obj): in function `__debugbreak':
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/_mingw.h:582: multiple definition of `__debugbreak'; ../libwidget-a0.a(foc.c.obj):C:/msys64/mingw64/include/_mingw.h:582: first defined here
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: ../libwidget-a0.a(maths.c.obj): in function `__fastfail':
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/_mingw.h:603: multiple definition of `__fastfail'; ../libwidget-a0.a(foc.c.obj):C:/msys64/mingw64/include/_mingw.h:603: first defined here
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: ../libwidget-a0.a(svpwm.c.obj): in function `__debugbreak':
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/_mingw.h:582: multiple definition of `__debugbreak'; ../libwidget-a0.a(foc.c.obj):C:/msys64/mingw64/include/_mingw.h:582: first defined here
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: ../libwidget-a0.a(svpwm.c.obj): in function `__fastfail':
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/_mingw.h:603: multiple definition of `__fastfail'; ../libwidget-a0.a(foc.c.obj):C:/msys64/mingw64/include/_mingw.h:603: first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

1. Why does Windows compiler add these functions to *each* source object?
2. What is the good way to resolve this error?

---

gcc.exe (Rev6, Built by MSYS2 project) 12.2.0

cmake version 3.25.1

Comment: Please show the content of linkLibs.rsp and your CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Which CMakeLists.txt? I don't have linkLibs.rsp

Answer (score 0):

I did find a solution. Perhaps not the most elegant, but working.

There is a file in mingw64 `intrin.h`. The reason for its existence is described [here](https://mingw-w64-public.narkive.com/9uy03D8V/what-is-the-purpose-of-intrin-h). Including it resolves the aforementioned build error.

Comment: This doesn't really help unless you explain where to include it and what you achieve with this inclusion. Simply including `intrin.h`  in a random C file results in a bunch of errors such as "incompatible type for argument 2 of '__builtin_ia32_broadcastf64x2_256_mask'"